# Create hyperlink to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

The first sheet of my workbook is like a contents page. Each cell in column A holds an IP address string. For each IP address string, there is a worksheet named with the IP address.

I want to turn the string in the cells in column A into hyperlinks to their corresponding sheets (cell A1 of the destination sheet).

I only need the VBA line that makes the hyperlink; I can figure out the looping, etc. Remember that the name of the sheet to be linked to is the same as the value of the cell that will become the link.

Research has only brought up forum posts that give a stack of code without explaining any of it.

Comment: what VBA do you already have?

Comment: Record a Macro and you will get that VBA line :)

Comment: why not insert a simple formula? `=HYPERLINK("[workbookname]sheetname!A1", "display text")`

Comment: You can just precede the address by `#` for the link location eg `"#Sheet1!A1"`. Better not to include workbook name in case the workbook is renamed or a copy is opened.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I recorded a macro making a hiperlink. This resulted.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(""[Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1!A1"",""CLICK HERE"")"
```

Answer (score 18):

This is the code I use for creating an index sheet.

```vb
Sub CreateIndexSheet()
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "Contents" 'Call whatever you like
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Prevents seeing all the flashing as it updates the sheet
    For Each wSheet In Worksheets
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & wSheet.Name & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=wSheet.Name
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'Moves down a row
    Next
    Range("A1").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").EntireRow.Delete 'Remove content sheet from content list
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Lee I've adopted this into my templates now.  I made one change - wrapping the worksheet name with a single quote in case users create sheets with spaces which breaks the hyperlink.                                                            `ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & wSheet.Name & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=wSheet.Name`

Answer (score 7):

Something like the following will loop through column A in the Control sheet and turn the values in the cells into Hyperlinks. Not something I've had to do before so please excuse bugs:

```
Sub CreateHyperlinks()

Dim mySheet As String
Dim myRange As Excel.Range
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Set myRange = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Control").Range("A1:A5") '<<adjust range to suit

For Each cell In myRange
    Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Control").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, Address:="", SubAddress:=cell.Value & "!A1" '<<from recorded macro
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: How could I have the macro link to a sequence of cells? for example in C1:C500 I have the index location of the cell I want referenced, so if C1 says "20" the macro should link the A1 to B20, if C2 says "30", link A2 to B30 etc. ?

Answer (score 3):

The "!" sign is the key element. If you have a cell object (like "mycell" in following code sample) and link a cell to this object you must pay attention to ! element.

You must do something like this:

```
.Cells(i, 2).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range(Cells(i, 2).Address), Address:="", _
     SubAddress:= "'" & ws.Name & "'" & _
     "!" & mycell.Address
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to hyperlink Sheet1 to all or corresponding sheets, then use simple vba code. If you wish to create a radio button, then assign this macro to that button ex "Home Page".

Here is it:

```
Sub HomePage()
'
' HomePage Macro
'


' This is common code to go to sheet 1 if do not change name for Sheet1
    'Sheets("Sheet1").Select
' OR 

' You can write you sheet name here in case if its name changes

    Sheets("Monthly Reports Home").Select
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This macro adds a hyperlink to the worksheet with the same name, I also modify the range to be more flexible, just change the first cell in the code. Works like a charm

```
Sub hyper()
 Dim cl As Range
 Dim nS As String

 Set MyRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B16")
 Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

 For Each cl In MyRange
  nS = cl.Value
  cl.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cl, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & nS & "'" & "!B16", TextToDisplay:=nS
 Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In my implementation, the cell I was referencing could have been several options.  I used the following format where 'ws' is the current worksheet being edited

```
For each ws in Activeworkbook.Worksheets
    For i…
       For j...
...
ws.Cells(i, j).Value = "=HYPERLINK(""#'" & SHEET-REF-VAR & "'!" & CELL-REF-VAR & """,""" & SHEET-REF-VAR & """)"
```