# Generating a table of contents using vba in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that retrieves data from an external source and then formats/graphs that data in individual worksheets. I have a large number of worksheets (100+) and I would like to create a table of contents column on my first worksheet

The way my macro works is that my first worksheet functions as my command worksheet. I have a list of serial numbers for oil wells (column A) that excel then follows and downloads relevant information from the internet.The information downloaded for each oil well is put into a new worksheet and then named based off the value in column C.

In column D I would like to insert a hyperlinked version of whatever text is in column C. This hyperlink will be linked to the sheet that was generated and named using Columns A and C.

I have attempted to create this on my own, but I cant make it work.

Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

I have  attached a picture showing what I would like as well. See below

[image]

Comment: Can you share what you have already tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel VBA create hyperlink to another sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813488/excel-vba-create-hyperlink-to-another-sheet)

Comment: What have you tried?  plus how are you invoking it?  Do you want to generate the hyperlinks via a button like the ones you already have, or could be invoked each time you open the sheet if a hyperlink does not already exist (as an example)

Comment: I have attempted the automatic macro recording, but I cant make it dynamic enough to select a new worksheet to hyperlink each time. It hyperlinks one sheet and then hyperlinks all other values to that one sheet.

Answer (score 1):

[Excel VBA create hyperlink to another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813488/excel-vba-create-hyperlink-to-another-sheet)

Courtesy of @curial:
I recorded a macro making a hiperlink. This resulted.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(""[Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1!A1"",""CLICK HERE"")"
```

For your specific application the formula would be:

```
=HYPERLINK(""[NameOfWorkbook.xlsx]" & C2 & "!A1"", C2)
```

Then copy that down.

Comment: Though it shows syntactically how to create a hyperlink, not sure that is exactly what is being asked, as he wants to create a large number of hyperlinks based on content of col C on each row where col C is populated

Comment: This is not quite working for me. it is giving me a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Chrismas007's answer, maybe this is what you need:

```
Sub Add_Hyperlinks()
    Dim lngLastRow As Long, i As Integer
    lngLastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lngLastRow
        Cells(i, 4).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & i - 1 & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:="'" & i - 1 & "'!A1"
    Next
End Sub
```

If you throw this into your existing sub (or keep it separate and call it in the main sub), it will go through, find the last row, and then loop from row 2 to that last row adding the =hyperlink formula where needed. Just make sure to edit the contents of that hyperlink formula as needed.

Update: This should fix it! There is a new formula for adding hyperlinks within the For loop that works (for me, at least)

Comment: This isnt working, It is giving me the error that it cannot open the specified file. It also is only hyperlinking to the first generated worksheet instead of changing the hyperlink each time to match the worksheet name

Comment: When I click the link I would like to be taken to another sheet in the same workbook.  I work for a oil and gas company and each sheet contains a single wells production information. Each sheet was named off of the well name. I would like to have a hyperlinked well name that will take me to that sheet in the workbook

Comment: No it is not.  I get a reference is not valid error