# Add hyperlinks in each worksheet back to the TOC sheet

Tags: excel, vbscript, hyperlink

I have an excel workbook with the first worksheet as the TOC sheet and many other sheets as contenct. I would like to use VBScript to add the hyperlink to each sheet which can be linked back to the TOC sheet. Any one who is familiar with VBScript could help me out?

Below is the VBScript code I created, but I got an error message at line 11 "Unknown runtime error".

```
Dim objExcel
   Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
   Wscript.Sleep 30
   objExcel.Application.Visible = False
   Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("path\test.xlsx",,False)
   objExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   objExcel.Workbooks(1).Activate
   Dim ShCount, sHyperlink, sDest
   ShCount = objExcel.Workbooks(1).Worksheets.Count
   For I = 2 To ShCount
Set sHyperlink=objExcel.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(I).Cells("A1")
Set sDest=objExcel.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Cells("A1")
Call sHyperlink.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add(sHyperlink, vbNullString, "'" & sDest.Parent.Name & "'!" & sDest.Address, vbNullString, sHyperlink.Value)
   Next
objExcel.Workbooks(1).SaveAs "path\test.xlsx", 51 
objExcel.Quit
set objExcel = nothing
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating a table of contents using vba in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27802849)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by adding a `=HYPERLINK()` formula to your cell:

Something like

```
objExcel.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(I).Cells("A1").Formula="HYPERLINK(""#'IndexSheetName'!A2"",""UserFriendlyName"")"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Add Hyperlinks Pointing to a TOC Worksheet

```vb
Option Explicit

' Create and reference a new instance of Excel ('xlApp'). 
Dim xlApp: Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
'xlApp.Visible = True ' use this while developing; it's 'False' by default

'Wscript.Sleep 30 ' ???

' Open and reference the workbook ('wb').
Dim wb: Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("path\Test.xlsx")

'xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False ' ???

' Store the number of worksheets in a variable ('wsCount').
Dim wsCount: wsCount = wb.Worksheets.Count
' Store the destination address, the parameter for the 3rd argument
' of 'Hyperlinks.Add', 'SubAddress', in a variable ('dAddress').
Dim dAddress: dAddress = "'" & wb.Worksheets(1).Name & "'!A1"

Dim sCell, sValue, i

For i = 2 To wsCount
    Set sCell = wb.Worksheets(i).Range("A1")
    sValue = vbNullString
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent Type mismatch error if error value
        sValue = CStr(sCell.Value)
    On Error Goto 0    
    ' The parameter of the 2nd argument, 'Address',  must be an empty string.
    ' The parameter of the 5th argument, 'TextToDisplay', cannot be
    ' an empty string, but it can be omitted when its parameter will default
    ' to the destination address (e.g. 'Sheet1!A1') 
    ' or to whatever is in the cell.
    If Len(sValue) > 0 Then
        sCell.Worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
            sCell, vbNullString, dAddress, , sCell.Value
    Else
        sCell.Worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add sCell, vbNullString, dAddress
    End If
Next

wb.Close True 
xlApp.Quit

'Set xlApp = Nothing ' ???
```