# Excel VBA assign hyperlink to a cell

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, macros

Currently I have VBA macro that will generate a page based on some information that I key into cell T3 on an overview page. What I would like to do is to have the same 'create page' button also automatically assign a hyperlink based on the value.

For instance, if I put brownj1 into cell t3, a page will be created and named 'brownj1', what I would also like the macro to achieve is to assign cell 'b3' which also has the name 'brownj1' to the newly created page. Another way I think would probably be a better way around it would be to search/loop through column B to locate the matching cell to T3 and then assign the hyperlink.

As I mentioned I already have the necessary code to generate the page and assign the name as the sheet name and all I am looking for is a formula to assign a hyperlink to a specific name as the page is being generated.

Comment: You've definitely been here long enough to know you have to show effort.

Comment: One way to do it would be to look at this page about how to create a hyperlink to a worksheet, then create a macro that loops through all the values in column B that says if Worksheets(cells(i, 2).Value) exists, create the hyperlink http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813488/excel-vba-create-hyperlink-to-another-sheet

Comment: I have never seen a right sidebar-linked question downvoted with -5 stars, so I was curious.  When I read your question, I added another downvote for your bad behavior.  You know the rules.  Show us what you tried.  Where is the code in "Currently I have VBA macro that will..." or "As I mentioned I already have the necessary code..."  Are you just being coy or superlazy?  Get with the program.

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting, Rich. Considering this question is 6 years old, I've moved on to other projects so even if I wanted to revisit and update, I wouldn't even know where to begin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sample of how to do that:

```
Sub createLink()
Dim lastRow As Integer, sheetCount As Integer, myRange As Excel.Range, c As Excel.Range
lastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
sheetCount = Application.Sheets.Count
Set myRange = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B" & lastRow)

For Each c In myRange
    For x = 1 To sheetCount
        If Worksheets(x).Name = c.Value Then
             Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:="", SubAddress:=c.Value & "!A1"
        End If
    Next x
Next c
End Sub
```