# How to auto insert a hyperlink in a cell based on 2 cell values

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I was wondering if someone could help.

I have a macro which I use as a change record as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

If ActiveSheet.Name = "ChangeRecord" Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False

UserName = Environ("USERNAME")

NewVal = Target.Value

Application.Undo

oldVal = Target.Value

lr = Sheets("ChangeRecord").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Sheets("ChangeRecord").Range("A" & lr) = Now
Sheets("ChangeRecord").Range("B" & lr) = ActiveSheet.Name
Sheets("ChangeRecord").Range("C" & lr) = Target.Address
Sheets("ChangeRecord").Range("D" & lr) = oldVal
Sheets("ChangeRecord").Range("E" & lr) = NewVal
Sheets("ChangeRecord").Range("F" & lr) = UserName

Target = NewVal

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

So, the changes are recorded in a separate sheet called ChangeRecord, and this is working just fine.

What I would like to do is also add a hyperlink in column G which takes me straight to the change record, so, if the cell value in column B is another worksheet named Scotland, and the cell that was changed is $A$21, then the hyperlink that is auto created in column G takes me to that cell on that worksheet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Best regards

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813488/excel-vba-create-hyperlink-to-another-sheet)

Answer (score 1):

Check the below code

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

If ActiveSheet.Name = "ChangeRecord" Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False

UserName = Environ("USERNAME")

NewVal = Target.Value

Application.Undo

oldVal = Target.Value

lr = Sheets("ChangeRecord").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Sheets("ChangeRecord").Range("A" & lr) = Now
Sheets("ChangeRecord").Range("B" & lr) = ActiveSheet.Name
Sheets("ChangeRecord").Range("C" & lr) = Target.Address
Sheets("ChangeRecord").Range("D" & lr) = oldVal
Sheets("ChangeRecord").Range("E" & lr) = NewVal
Sheets("ChangeRecord").Range("F" & lr) = UserName
Sheets("ChangeRecord").Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Sheets("ChangeRecord").Range("G" & lr), _
            Address:="", SubAddress:=Target.Worksheet.Name & "!" & Target.Address, _
            TextToDisplay:="Changes"
Target = NewVal

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, works a treat.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you need. please check.

```
Sheets("ChangeRecord").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("ChangeRecord").Range("G" & CStr(lr)), Address:="", SubAddress:=ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Sheets("ChangeRecord").Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Address, TextToDisplay:=ActiveSheet.Name
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I tried your suggestion as well, this doesn't show the target cell/cell range in the hyperlink output, however, as mentioned above, and modified slightly, this is the one that I like as it displays the target cell range nicely spaced and with a screentip: Sheets("ChangeRecord").Hyperlinks.Add _
    Anchor:=Sheets("ChangeRecord").Range("G" & lr), _
    Address:="", SubAddress:="" & Sh.Name & " - " & Target.Address, ScreenTip:=" Link to changed cell/cell range "