# Excel - Creating Hyperlinks to the sheet with same name

Tags: excel, creation

So i have a workbook with 250+ names in Column 'A'. I have created individual sheet for every name and the sheet name corresponds to the same name as in cell on First sheet.
I am trying to see how can i automtically convert that name to a hyprlink, such that when user clicks it, it takes him/her to the sheet which corresponds to the name.

Example:

**Column A on Sheet #1**
Smith
Nancy
Joe
Jill
Brian

And i have 5 sheets, named Smith, Nancy, Joe, Jill and Brian

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA create hyperlink to another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813488/excel-vba-create-hyperlink-to-another-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it, and it works for me.

Follow the below steps

- List `Smith`, `Nancy`, `Joe`, `Jill`, `Brian` on Column A on Sheet #1.
- Create individual sheets with names `Smith`, `Nancy`, `Joe`, `Jill`, `Brian`
- Right click on `Smith` cell, and select Hyperlink.
  [click here to view the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQcOu.jpg)
- Select `This Document` tab --> Cell Reference --> Smith [click here to view the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki3J6.jpg)
- Repeat it for all other values.

Comment: I noticed that i didn't mention that the list is very long. I am trying to get some kind of VBA that will do the trick.