# Sequential cell hyperlinks to created sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm in the process of creating a workbook that tracks temporary personnel coming into the shop and their progress through a training program.

I have two pages, a main sheet which lists the temporary personnel under the following headings:  Name, Start Date and End Date.  There is also a button to create new sheets.  The second sheet is a template used for formatting new sheets.

What works currently is:

Add New Sheet button - creates a new sheet, prompts the user to name the sheet and formats the new sheet using the template.

What I would like to add:

After the user enters the temp person's information, they click the add new sheet button.  In addition to the functions already working I would like the button to hyperlink the "Name" cell that the user just entered information into so that cell will take the user to the training tracker sheet for that person.

Also, I would like the button to take the information (Name, Start Date and End Date) for that person and copy to the new sheet.

I don't have much of a background in coding, I've managed to take some example code and make minor changes to get what's working now.  I don't know if what I'm asking is possible or not.  The main thing is to ensure that each time the user enters a new person's information and clicks the add new sheet button the information for the correct person gets copied to the new sheet and the hyperlink will take the user to the correct person's training tracker.

Thanks for any help, it's appreciated.

The following is the code for what I have working so far.

```
Private Sub AddSheet_Click()
Dim DefaultSheetName As String


Worksheets("Template").Copy Before:=Worksheets("Template")

DefaultSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogWorkbookName).Show

If ActiveSheet.Name = DefaultSheetName Then
    MsgBox "You didn't name the new sheet." & vbCrLf & _
           "Processing cancelled", vbExclamation
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: My advise is to split your coding questions into smaller ones. This way you have better chance that someone will answer your questions. And don't expect that you will get working code if you write long specification in the question. Good luck in your learning to code :)

Comment: Sounds like you've got a good project for yourself and with the description of what you want, you've also set up a specification for the features you need. As @MarisB. suggests, take things one step at a time. [Here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9813626/4717755) that will show you how to create a hyperlink from the person's name to the new sheet that was created. Just add bits of code one small feature at a time and test it to make sure it works before tackling the next part. You'll get there!